# wait for thread to finish (without "waiting") before next iteration

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm checking for certain condition inside a loop, if that condition is met then I want to initiate a new thread.

Within the thread I make an update, that update will have effect on the condition on the next iteration.

My concern is that the thread won't finish (such as update database or call remote resource) until the next iteration and at the next iteration the condition will still evaluate the same so will have two or more threads run before the update is initiated.

I can't have any timer/wait or anything like that. The loop has to be running constantly and instantaneously.

A solution I'm thinking is to have a flag which gets updated inside the thread, and condition checks this same flag until the thread is finished.

Thanks for any feedback or suggestions.

Comment: Not clear.. do you want to use the changes immediately from next iteration?

Comment: no I don't expect to because it might take some time to execute some procedure before the next iteration, so not for the same condition. but i don't want to stall it, it must keep on going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you want to do, but it sounds like you have a massive event loop. As part of it, when State == X, you spawn a child process. The child then sets State = Y, and you proceed to do stuff with Y. After spawning a child, you want to wait until State = Y, while still executing the rest of the loop. Sound right?

In that case, just set a flag as you spawn the child, and only spawn the child when the flag is not set.

*edit*
You need to set the flag in the main thread, not in the child thread as you suggested. You have no guarantee that the child will get to execute anything before the main thread gets back to the loop.

Comment: yes you are correct with the massive event loop. Yes thats what I meant the flag will be set in the main, and the child thread will update its state. So the condition check will check that flag constantly. Does that sound right?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a thread - threads operate a synchronously.

You require synchronous behaviour: Perform the update in the main thread.

Comment: When you mean "main thread", are you referring to the main loop? Its simply a loop, and inside that loop I have a condition (if) check, if it evaluates to true I start a new thread inside it. but because there is some procedure that might take some time inside the thread (such as update database) i want to make sure i don't create another of the same thread on the next iteration.

Comment: I don't think I can use sync behavior for this, this cannot in anyway slow down the initial main loop.

Comment: By main thread I mean the thread your loop is executing in. More simply, just don't use threads

Comment: Post some code. There are a couple of ways to get the thread to set a value that your loop can use, but it would be easier to see some code so I can tailor a solution for you.

Comment: thanks Bohemian, I believe I found a good solution now. Thanks for your response.